# Kivy: Coordinates

Tags: python, kivy

In the following code i don't explain two problems:

1. If I use method `__init__`  --> Scene.canvas = None
2. I  don't underestand to relative position objects on image.

I wanted to obtain knowledges about coordinates system from Kivy Manual, but without success.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image    
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse

class Scene(Widget):
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 100
        self.dir = 1
    """
    def set_par(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 100
        self.dir = 1

    def create_ball(self):
        with self.canvas:
            Ellipse(pos = (0,0), size = (40, 40))
        img = Image(pos = (0,0), source = 'image1.png') # square 40x40pixels  
        self.add_widget(img)          

class SceneApp(App):
    def build(self):
        scene = Scene()
        scene.create_ball()

        return scene

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SceneApp().run()
```

Printscreen form my code:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call `super()` in your `__init__` method. So `Widget`'s `__init__` method just get completely overrited.
Then use `FloatLayout` instead of `Widget`
You can to do something like this:

```python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse

Window.size = (300, 300)

class Scene(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scene,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = 300,300

    def create_ball(self):
        img = Image(pos = (-130, -130), source = 'image1.png') # square 40x40pixels
        self.add_widget(img)
        with self.canvas:
            Ellipse(pos = (0,0), size = (40, 40))

class SceneApp(App):
    def build(self):
        scene = Scene()
        scene.create_ball()
        return scene

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SceneApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank You! Is universal criterion for using: Widget - Layout - BoxLayout?